# How to handle error with an array of Observable with forkJoin?

Tags: angular, error-handling, promise, rxjs, observable

I fetch observable stream from API for my angular app and I want to handle error with forkjoin.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { forkJoin, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';

//An array of observable
let source$ = this.selectedItem.map(item => {
  let payload = {foo: item.foo};
  return this.apiService.updateBar(payload);
});

//Action when a response has been received for all observable
forkJoin(source$).subscribe(
   () => {
     this.action1();
     this.action2();
     this.action3();
   }
)
```

I searched how to handle error into the official rxjs documentation of [forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) and they don't mention how to handle error when you have an array of Observable as input.

So I tried to handle the error on the observable directly and this is almost working:

```
  let source$ = this.selectedItem.map(item => {
      let payload = {foo: item.foo};
      return this.apiService.updateBar(payload).pipe(
        catchError(
          msg => {
           this.errorAction1();
           this.errorAction1();
           this.errorAction1();
          }
        )
      );
    })
```

But I got this error:

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide
> an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

So, I wonder how to implement error handle properly with forkJoin? And how to fix this error ? Thank you a lot

Comment: What is your requirement? You want to proceed when any one/two, etc observables fail or do you want to catch the error when any one fails?

Comment: Also, you might be getting *You provided 'undefined' w...* error because you aren't returning anything from your cathError

Comment: When one fails, I want to catch the error and display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to catch the error when anyone of then fails then add the `error` callback in your subscribe. There is no need to add separate error handlers for each Observable.

```
forkJoin(source$).subscribe(
    () => {
        this.action1();
        this.action2();
        this.action3();
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
)
```

Comment: Yeah it's working fine, I tried this but something was missing. I tried again with:      .pipe(
        catchError(
          error => {throw error;}
        )
      ); and this is working :D thank you